# How can I convert hex string to binary?

Tags: input, hex, mips, data-conversion, spim

My problem is getting a 64-bit key from user. For this I need to get 16 characters as string which contains hexadecimal characters (123456789ABCDEF). I got the string from user and I reached characters with the code below. But I don't know how to convert character to 4-bit binary

```
.data 


insert_into: 
    .word 8 

Ask_Input:  
    .asciiz "Please Enter a Key which size is 16, and use hex characters : " 


key_array: 
    .space 64

.text
.globl main


main: 

    la $a0, Ask_Input 

    li $v0, 4 
    syscall 

    la $a0, insert_into 
    la $a1, 64 
    li $v0, 8
    syscall

    la $t0, insert_into
    li $t2, 0
    li $t3, 0
  loop_convert:
        lb $t1, ($t0)
        addi $t0, $t0, 1 

        beq $t1, 10, end_convert

# Now charcter is in $t1 but 
  #I dont know how to convert it to 4 bit binary and storing it


        b loop_convert

    end_convert:        

    li $v0, 10  # exit
    syscall
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have a look at this [ASCII table](http://www.ascii-code.com/) you will see that hex-code for numbers from 9 and below  are 0x9 and for capital letters this is between 0x41 and 0x5A A-Z determine if its a number or character, you see if theres a number its quite done, if it were a character mask with 0x15 to get the four bits.

If you want to include lowercase letters do same procedure with masking and determine if its a char between 0x61 and 0x7A

Answer (score 0):

I don't think masking with 0x15 as @Joelmob's opinion is the right solution, because

```
'A' = 0x41 → 0x41 & 0x15 = 0
'B' = 0x42 → 0x42 & 0x15 = 0
'C' = 0x43 → 0x43 & 0x15 = 1
'D' = 0x44 → 0x44 & 0x15 = 4
'E' = 0x45 → 0x45 & 0x15 = 5
'F' = 0x46 → 0x46 & 0x15 = 4
```

which doesn't produce any relevant binary values

The easiest way is **subtracting the range's lower limit from the character value**. I'll give the idea in C, you can easily convert it to MIPS asm

```c
if ('0' <= ch && ch <= '9')
{
    return ch - '0';
}
else if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'F')
{
    return ch - 'A' + 10;
}
else if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'f')
{
    return ch - 'a' + 10;
}
```

Another way to implement:

```c
if ('0' <= ch && ch <= '9')
{
    return ch & 0x0f;
}
else if (('A' <= ch && ch <= 'F') || ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'f'))
{
    return (ch & 0x0f) + 9;
}
```

However this can be further optimized to a single comparison using the technique describes in the following questions

- [Fastest way to determine if an integer is between two integers (inclusive) with known sets of values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17095324/995714)
- [Check if number is in range on 8051](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29519796/995714)

Now the checks can be rewritten as below

```c
if ((unsigned char)(ch - '0') <= ('9'-'0'))
if ((unsigned char)(ch - 'A') <= ('F'-'A'))
if ((unsigned char)(ch - 'a') <= ('f'-'a'))
```

Any modern compilers can do this kind of optimization, [here is an example output](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwoIL4WBAHQIN2DgAYAguYsiFBABwB9AqoSYAHrQi39Tl8gQASmsOAHY%2BS1Uo1TwAM1UIMCkzJPUtDQARVQD1LgA2bjzshDTNTNUkgE4k4Mjo%2BuJMAjEWYtUAWgrkpI0Ii3rMBkFMGPjEqQtUjTLZLJzCwrbp8qSAMRrreoamlrbOpMmpXJ5VWjNezejB4dGEpKYp9Nml/MX5p6yk2I26rdVG5rEVo5fZSB5Hfinc6yPoDIaYS5/AG7MzuVarACqF0sYQyIUsPgczlcHi43jsfmKtSs4URt3GKQhHxeBXyS2ZVR%2B/T%2B/x2QJZqlRZli2O5UWuIziCXGh1K5XmrzZ7xmnyk6ykgXUoTK2ruYMeKpZbxKy2eXxq1J5vMBrQgCqKQtimshlVFcOGdO2NsFaMxotx1g1jGkAFYpKQWNIzOHUNIyrxIcIxBJcrJaOGCFGNYFSABrECyAAsBi4hdkoVoIZDeTMFdC1eDUkL4YAtnQzGYI1nSLGpOHBCBO5nkkG4LAkGgWwAHPAMTBkCh21DT2fzkAtvBTwQhwakWKzgjzgcQABG3ZPCiYxAAntJ06RJy3MPoAPIsBi3kekLAt1jAOfdvgjTIAQeAAG6YAOX4eJgyAiIed7hnYgzdgQxB4G2UjpjmzBsCg/D8IweAngOkA5qgU6gagLBQe0L5cB0ADqTAMAwHSxBBxAnqgwztEwggtv2ojiJItA4aG4aRl%2BvYALIAJIAAoAMqqMAyDIKoIYGIWCSDJqEC4IQJCpvQqiaMuM5zsQqayJq8Z8LwGZZoEOZuEwWDEJQOb5rIXAGJUZyVFwXBmMFhYhqWsiNs2pBtmcnZSdGPbSP2g6kMO0Y5mOiAoBZq4LpQk6WWuSh/s4xAiCwuZ7geR6UGeX4XiwV6fvej7PgQb4foBmC/mwAFfkBsGgRBUFJTBcEIVhSH6ChX5oRhiE4X%2B%2BEJrwREkfA5GUXg1G0fRTEsWx7QEFewBNKoG5bkJyaieJUhhl20nSO49h5O0eQ6aVbAJGhlW5vphlENZcimeZK5WamIZ2QRjnpc5rmYO5a4QN5BZ%2BfY4WyHkpa0Hk9iyB29AMNIMVxR2T1Jb2qVDgjjZcJJ3bU/DI4uaQnGCLtkaFkAA%3D%3D%3D)

```c
hex2(unsigned char):
        andi    $4,$4,0x00ff     # ch, ch
        addiu   $2,$4,-48      # tmp203, ch,
        sltu    $2,$2,10         # tmp204, tmp203,
        bne     $2,$0,$L13
        nop
        andi    $2,$4,0xdf       # tmp206, ch,
        addiu   $2,$2,-65      # tmp210, tmp206,
        sltu    $2,$2,6  # tmp211, tmp210,
        beq     $2,$0,$L12         #, tmp211,,
        andi    $4,$4,0xf        # tmp212, ch,

        j       $31
        addiu   $2,$4,9        # D.2099, tmp212,

$L12:
        j       $31
        li      $2,255                  # 0xff   # D.2099,

$L13:
        j       $31
        andi    $2,$4,0xf        # D.2099, ch,
```