# Check if number is in range on 8051

Tags: assembly, embedded, 8051

I have received a character over UART, and need to validate if it's a number character.

Normally I'd do

```
if (char >= '0' && char <= '9') { /* VALID */ }
```

However, I have to do it **in assembly**.

I haven't found any compare instruction (so I assume there is none).

How can I do this?

```
    mov A, SBUF    ; load the number

    ; -- pseudocode --
    cmp A, #'0'    ; In AVR, I'd do it this way
    brlt fail      ; but I'm new to 8051
    cmp A, #'9'
    brge fail
    ; -- pseudocode --

    ; number is good

fail:
```

---

edit: ok here's what I have now but it doesn't work

```
;======================================================
; check if r1 is number char -> r0 = 1 or 0
;------------------------------------------------------
fn_isnum:
    PUSH acc
    PUSH 1

    MOV r1,A

    SUBB A,#'0'
    JC isnum_bad

    MOV A,r1

    SUBB A,#'9'+1
    JC isnum_bad

    POP 1
    POP acc

    MOV r0,#1
    RET 

isnum_bad:

    POP 1
    POP acc

    MOV r0,#0
    RET
;======================================================
```

Comment: You can use `SUBB` or `ADD` instead in conjunction with `JC`/`JNC`. Is that enough hint?

Comment: Yeah I see the idea of using carry and then JC and JNC, I'm just not really sure how to do it.

Comment: For example, you can subtract `'0'` and if you got a carry that means the value was less, so you should jump to invalid case.  Similarly, subtract `'9'+1` and if that does not produce carry, that means the value was bigger than `9` so again invalid.

Comment: You the addition or subtraction operation to potentially set the flag, then the conditional jump to act on it.

Comment: @Jester could you please check my code that i just added? I tried ti implement it but it won't work

Comment: If `A` has the value `'5'`, then what will the state of the carry bit be when you do, `SUBB A, #'9'+1`?

Comment: Yeah I messed up there, it's working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is compile it in C and check the listing file.  Here is what my compiler produces.

```
MOV     A, SBUF
CLR     C
SUBB    A, #030H
JC      ?C0026
MOV     A, SBUF
SETB    C
SUBB    A, #039H
JNC     ?C0026

; Put instructions here to execute when the code is valid

?C0026:
```

Comment: but that's not the most optimized way and it needs 2 checks + 2 jumps

Comment: Get a better compiler if it doesn't optimize range-checks for you.  GCC and clang use the technique that phuclv's answer shows, at least when compiling for mainstream CPUs.  (I don't know if either one can target 8051).

Answer (score 3):

Using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17095324/995714), `if (a >= '0' && a <= '9')` can be transformed into

```
if ((unsigned char)(a - '0') <= ('9'-'0'))
```

which saves you a comparison and a jump. Now **only a single comparison is enough**

The result might be like this

```
    SUBB A, #'0'  ;  A = a - '0'
    CLR  C
    MOV  R1, A    ; R1 = a - '0'
    MOV  A, #9    ;  A = '9' - '0'
    SUBB A, R1    ;  C = 1 if ('9' - '0') < (a - '0')
    JC   bad:     ; jump when C != 0, i.e. !((a - '0') <= ('9' - '0'))
valid:
    ; do something
bad:
```

Most modern compilers know how to optimize this range check. I can't find a 8051 online compiler nor do I have an offline compiler for it, but AVR would be close enough to give a demo. AVR gcc gives the same output for [both the original condition and the transformed one](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'char+getMask(char+a)%0A%7B%0A++++return+(unsigned+char)(a+-+!'0!')+%3C%3D+(!'9!'-!'0!')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Achar+getMask2(char+a)%0A%7B%0A++++return+a+%3E%3D+!'0!'+%26%26+a+%3C%3D+!'9!'%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:31.17831909738605,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:avrg464,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'AVR+gcc+4.6.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:35.48834756928063,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

```
    mov r25,r24          ; input in r24
    subi r25,lo8(-(-48)) ; r25 = input - '0'
    ldi r24,lo8(1)       ; r24 = 1
    cpi r25,lo8(10)      ; if r25 < 10
    brlo .L2             ; jump to .L2
    ldi r24,lo8(0)       ; r24 = 0
.L2:
    ret                  ; return value in r24
```

## Update:

[Sample output for 8051](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:10,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:10),source:'char+getMask(char+a)%0A%7B%0A++++return+(unsigned+char)(a+-+!'0!')+%3C%3D+(!'9!'-!'0!')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Achar+getMask2(char+a)%0A%7B%0A++++return+a+%3E%3D+!'0!'+%26%26+a+%3C%3D+!'9!'%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C+source+%231',t:'0')),k:32.13585891574134,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:sdcc400,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:'--opt-code-speed',selection:(endColumn:23,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:23,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:23,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:23,startLineNumber:17),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'SDCC+4.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C',t:'0')),header:(),k:67.86414108425865,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) from SDCC

```
        mov     r7,dpl
        cjne    r7,#0x30,00110$
00110$:
        jc      00103$
        mov     a,r7
        add     a,#0xff - 0x39
        jnc     00104$
00103$:
        mov     r7,#0x00
        sjmp    00105$
00104$:
        mov     r7,#0x01
00105$:
        mov     dpl,r7
        ret
```